# R adding element to Dataframe at specific position

Tags: r

I want to add a row to a dataframe in R at a specific position. I am aware that there are solutions for this on this site, yet they don't seem to work. I know rbind is rather slow, but given that I only need to do it for a single element it doesn't matter:

Example:

```
vector_labour_brexit.m <- data.frame("value" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

temp <- rbind(vector_labour_brexit.m[1:5,], data.frame("value"=5000), 
                            vector_labour_brexit.m[6:nrow(vector_labour_brexit.m),])
```

The desired result is obviously `1,2,3,4,5,5000,6,7,8,9`, yet I get `1,5000,6`. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `add_row` to add a specific row at a location

```
library(tibble)
add_row(vector_labour_brexit.m , .before = 6, value = 5000)
#   value
#1      1
#2      2
#3      3
#4      4
#5      5
#6   5000
#7      6
#8      7
#9      8
#10     9
```

---

The issue in the OP's code was due to `drop = TRUE` by default when there is a single column or row, it drops the dimensions

```
vector_labour_brexit.m[1:5,]
```

If we add `drop = FALSE` while subsetting, it would work

Comment: This does not work for me. With .before it says: "Error in remove_rownames(out) : is.data.frame(.data) is not TRUE", while with before it says: "Error: New rows in `add_row()` must use columns that already exist:
* Can't find column `before` in `.data`.".

Comment: @ToTom. it is working for me with the example showedd

Comment: That is strange. With the values I wrote in my first post it doesn't work for me. I am running R 3.6.1. Anyway, the solution with drop=FALSE works fine so it doesn't matter. Thank you!

Comment: @ToTom I am using `R 3.6.2`, but. it may be because. of `tibble` version

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when indexing data.frames that only have one column in the result, the returned value is simplified to a vector which confuses `rbind`. To be safe you can do

```
vector_labour_brexit.m <- data.frame("value" = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

temp <- rbind(vector_labour_brexit.m[1:5,,drop=FALSE],
              data.frame("value"=5000), 
              vector_labour_brexit.m[6:nrow(vector_labour_brexit.m),,drop=FALSE])
```

Comment: Thank you, however, now the position next to code say 1,2,3,4,5,61,7,8,9,10, instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. Is this just a view problem or what happened?

Comment: Original row names are preserved by data.frames and new ones are created for the new data.frames. Do you care about the row names? It really shouldn't cause any trouble. you could Run `rownames(temp) <- NULL` to "reset" the names

Comment: Thank you! Actually I don't need them for now but wasn't sure if it will become a problem later on!